# Connect 8 Taxonomies to One (Main) taxonomy. How to?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've started a new WordPress project. I'm trying to develop a movie database on wordpress.

I've created 4 custom taxonomies (all of them "tags" based, non-hierarchical):

*1) people
2) actors
3) directors
4) writers*

What do I need to do is to connect **2,3,4** taxonomies to **1** (people), because sometimes same person can be an "actor" and "director".

Is this possible ?

Comment: Sorry, not 8 taxonomies. Just 4.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using custom post types already, one suggestion is that you take a look at hierarchical post types. [Toolset Types](https://wp-types.com/) has support for this which I think would suit your situation better than using tags.

From what I can understand you have a custom post type called "Movies" and for each "Movie" there can be several "People" related to that movie, that has one or more "Roles" (director, actor etc.).

If that's the case, you could setup another post type called "People" and add a field of checkboxes for each role there is. You can then create a person (People) and select several roles for that person.

Then it's just a matter of displaying the output in a so called "View" (Toolset terminology).

Best of luck!